# How to display a menu of articles by category in joomla

Tags: templates, joomla, menu, joomla3.0

I'm relatively new to Joomla and I'm updating a web site from 1.5 to 3.x. Everything seemed to go fine except that the template in the previous version was showing a dynamic drop down menu that displayed each article organized by category. 
[image: this is what the drop down menu looks like]

I was wondering how I can show this menu. The code in the template is:

```
 <div id="moomenuE"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" style="topmenu" /><br /></div>
```

so I get that the position would be 'user3' but I can't seem to find a way to display such a menu. There were NO Menu's or Menu Items in the Menu Manager from the previous version so I'm not sure if I need to create one for the 3.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the previous version, but maybe the menu was hardcoded.  In Joomla 3.0 you just need to create a menu and some menu entries (worked in previous versions too). After doing so you have to add a module (Extensions -> Module Manager). The position of the module is "user3" in your case.Now only choose the menu and click save. The menu is now shown in the module placed at the specific position.

For more detailed information take a look at:

[menu](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x%3aAdding_a_new_menu)

[module](http://docs.joomla.org/Help33%3aExtensions_Module_Manager)